# Headings will not word-break

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure where the problem is coming from but my h1 and h2 takes are splitting the word rather than breaking word-breaking.

Here is a link to the site I'm working on https://helium.marketing

I've tried manually adding a snippet after a bunch of Googling but nothing seems to work. Here's the snippet.

```
    p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
        white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
        white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
        word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    }
```

Comment: In Safari 12 words are breaked on small screens as wanted.

Comment: What do you mean by “splitting the word rather than breaking word-breaking”? You want it to look like … and instead it looks like …?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 47, too...

Comment: I can replicate this problem on FF67. On narrow screens the words are broken rather than breaking on the space between the words (which I believe the OP desires).

Comment: *Which* heading are you having problems with? Please describe *EXACTLY* what your problem is?

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be the white-space: pre-wrap; needed to be white-space: normal; and overflow: visible;

It didn't fix it when I injected the code in Chrome but on a browser refresh, it resolved the issue. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The property you're looking for is not word-wrap, it's [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)
Check out the snippet example.

Hope this helps

```css
h1, p {
  width: 100px;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Last night, I had the best steak ever in the nearby town restaurant</p>
```